# I can not access the index of array with using for loop but I can do it manually

Tags: java, arrays, file, split, bufferedreader

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\nginx.access.log");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    /* read log line by line */
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  
    {
        /* parse strLine to obtain what you want */
        list.add(strLine);
    }
           
    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
           
    for (int i=0;i<stringArr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(stringArr[i]); 
               
    }
           
    fstream.close();
          
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

- When I try to print `System.out.println(stringArr[0]);`-->First line
  of txt
- Also,`System.out.println(stringArr[1]);`-->Second line of txt etc.

  But when I use for loop to print all the lines of text,it starts with a random line.
  I can not see any mistake on my for loop codes.I need your help.

Comment: Why do you convert the list to an array? Still, the code looks correct (if outdated and clumsy).

Comment: Just in case, if you're using Java 8, `Files.readAllLines` is pretty convenient : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllLines_Path_path_Charset_cs_.htm

Comment: I will send the every line of textfile to the logparser class ,for this reason I converted the list to an array Kayaman.

Comment: Thooomas I am not using Java 8.Problem still ongoing :(

Comment: Please show the code in its non-working situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code works. All lines of my test files are printed in the correct order.

Could it be, that your console has a limited number of lines? With a limit of 100 lines you would loose the first 5 lines after printing 105 lines. This would then look as if your program started to print the 6th line first.

Windows' cmd has a limited number of lines. Eclipse has a setting to limit/unlimit the number of lines.

To check whether that's your problem, execute your program and redirect its output into a file, then compare that file to the original file:

```
java YourProgram > output
FC "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\nginx.access.log" output
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend I changed the limit and it solved my problem..